# Write Recursive Function to loop through the Collection object in Objective C using Swift language

Tags: recursion, swift, swift-playground, generics

*I have seen people struggling to write an effective recursive function. Almost certainly, people don't get the recursive function working right at the first attempt.*

*This post will help the developers understand what actually needs to be done to write a proper recursive function. Also, get it right at the first attempt.*

Please see the Answer below:

Comment: This is not a Question.  (And frankly, even as an attempt to educate, I don't think this is particularly useful or helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

Speaking really generally, one way of thinking about recursive functions is to go through three steps each time:

1. Identify the base case

   - this is when you know to stop recursing
   - it is normally the simplest possible input to your function
2. Write a step case which will enable your function to eventually terminate

   - don't worry about the result yet
   - focus on making your input a bit 'smaller' in the relevant sense (a smaller number, a shorter array etc)
3. Modify the step case so that the correct result is returned

   - in other words, perform a unit of work

---

Take the example of working out the digits of a number.
This can be done using tail recursion, which is one common kind of recursion.

With the above formulation:

1. our base case is a single digit number;
2. our step case needs to recurse using a number with less digits; and
3. we need to make sure that we actually are building up an array of digits each time.

---

And so if we were to implement this in Swift, we'd end up with a conceptually simple result:

```
extension Int {
    func digitsInBase(base: Int) -> [Int] {
        /*
         * Check for the 'base case', ie the simplest input
         * We can immediately deal with this situation
         */
        if self < base {
            return [self]
        }

        /*
         * Here, we have the 'step case'
         * The idea is to break the problem into small parts, while
         * making sure we get a bit closer to the base case each time
         */
        return (self/base).digitsInBase(base) + [self%base]
    }

    // convenience property for a common base
    var digits: [Int] {
        return self.digitsInBase(10)
    }
}

123.digits // [1, 2, 3]
7.digitsInBase(2) // [1, 1, 1]
```

---

There's nothing *conceptually* more difficult to extending this to something like a loop, as the other answer does, but it's a mistake to think that all recursion involves loops.

To take the other answer's example of recursively summing a sequence, we make a base/step decision on each element:

1. the base case is an element which can be converted to a floating point number;
2. the step case is an element which is a sequence; and
3. we need to add to our result either the element itself, or the recursive sum of its elements, each time.

Comment: Agreed!! @Sapi, Thanks for the valuable input.

Answer (score -1):

***What is Recursive Function?***
Recursive function is a block of code that calls itself again and again until the break condition is satisfied.

***Important aspects of Recursive Function:***

1. *A looping block (E.g., for-loop)*
   **1.1** Write a loop that will iterate the topmost collection
   **1.2** An If condition, Inside this if-condition, break the loop when the required condition is satisfied
   **1.3** An else condition to call the recursive function in order to loop through the child collection
2. *A recursive function that calls itself when the break condition is not satisfied*
   **2.1** Write a loop that will iterate the child collection
   **2.2** An If condition, Inside this if-condition, break the loop when the required condition is satisfied
   **2.3** An else condition to call the self function in order to loop through the child collection

***Sample Code:***

```
import UIKit

let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let arr2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
let arr3 = [11,12,13,14,15]
let arr4 = [16,17,18,19,20]
let arr5 = [arr1, arr2, 26, 27]
let arr6 = [arr3, arr4, 28]
let arrMain = [arr5, arr6, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

var compareNumber:Int = 5
var foundNumber:Int = 0

func recurringFunc(numbers: NSArray) -> Void {
    for number in numbers{
        "the number is \(number)"
        if number is Int{
            if number.isEqual(compareNumber){
                foundNumber = number as Int;
                break
            }
        }

        if number is NSArray{
            "the number is \(number)"
            recurringFunc(number as NSArray)
        }
    }
}

for numbers in arrMain{

    numbers

    if  numbers is Int{
        "the number is \(numbers)"
        if numbers.isEqual(compareNumber){
            foundNumber = numbers as Int;
            break
        }
    }

    if numbers is NSArray{
        "the number is \(numbers)"
        recurringFunc(numbers as NSArray)
   }

}

foundNumber
```

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to help, but that code isn't particularly useful.  What's with the functions returning nothing and relying on global variables?!

Comment: Thanks @Sapi. This is only a sample code to demonstrate how to make a call to the recursive function and break out of it. The global variable is used to only display output in the Swift Playground environment.

Comment: Your main loop `for numbers in arrMain{ ...}` repeats the work of the recursive function and can simply be replaced by `recurringFunc(arrMain)`. I.e. the points #1 and #2 in your recipe are the same and are usually implemented only once. – Using global variables for both input and output data is not good style and should not be done in a recipe for a "proper recursive function". – Your statement that a looping block is an important aspect of a recursive function is at least misleading. That may be correct in this particular use-case, but not generally.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Martin, I too realized it lately.